# the return order of pthread_join() in C

Tags: c, multithreading, join

I am a little bit confused about the return order of pthread_join(). Let's say I have the following code. Is the order of the joined threads returned in this order: s2, s3, t2, s1, t1, main (implicit thread)?

All the threads **s1, s2, s3, t1, and t2** join to the main thread, right? I found this concept confusing. Thanks for help.

```
int main()
{
    pthread_t t1, t2;
    pthread_t s1, s2, s3;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, tseries, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, tseries, NULL);
    pthread_create(&s1, NULL, sseries, NULL);
    pthread_create(&s2, NULL, sseries, NULL);

    pthread_create(&s3, NULL, create_subthread, NULL);

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(s1, NULL);

    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    pthread_join(s3, NULL);

    pthread_join(s2, NULL);

    pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`pthread_join` waits for the thread you reference to exit (join). It will thus wait in the order you require, but the threads may have exited long before you wait for them to join.

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_join(t1, NULL);` will be blocked till thread t1 exits and joins even if other threads have exited before thread t1.